# Get only those string where specific ratio condition meets using diff tool SequenceMatcher

Tags: python, pandas

Any example where I can get two strings in a column of a dataframe when ratio condition met?

Example - While comparing one string with column of a dataframe, it should return only those when SequenceMatcher.ratio() > 0.8.

Comment: Can you add some data sample, [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with filter by lambda function in [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html):

```
text = 'my text'
df1 = df[df['col'].apply(lambda x: SequenceMatcher(None, x, text).ratio()) > 0.8]
```